# When using GADT in OCaml, how can I remove the 'less general definition' error message on a function?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, algebraic-data-types, gadt

I've been struggling with GADTs in OCaml recently. I'm trying to write an interpreter for a simple language, with different kinds of terms :

```
type (_, _) term =
  | Const : lit -> (state, value) term
  | Var : ident -> (state, value) term
  | Plus : expr * expr -> (state, value) term
  | Equ : expr * expr -> (state, value) term
  | Neg : expr -> (state, value) term
  | Skip : (state, state) term
  | Asn : ident * expr -> (state, state) term
  | Seq : stat * stat -> (state, state) term
  | If : expr * stat * stat -> (state, state) term
  | While : expr * stat -> (state, state) term
and expr = (state, value) term
and stat = (state, state) term
```

An ('a, 'b) term is a term that, when evaluated with an 'a, returns a 'b (typically, expressions are evaluated with a state and return a value, and statements are just modifying a given state into another one).

I've been trying to create functions for the interpreter, and I'm getting a weird error message that I cannot understand very well. This is the evaluating function :

```
let rec eval : type a b. a -> (a, b) term -> b = fun state term ->
  match term with
  | Const lit -> eval_lit_int state lit
  | Var ident -> eval_var eval state ident
  | Plus(e1, e2) -> eval_add eval state e1 e2
  | Equ(e1, e2) -> eval_eq eval state e1 e2
  | Neg e -> eval_neg eval state e
  | Skip -> eval_skip eval state
  | Asn(ident, e) -> eval_asn eval state ident e
  | Seq(s1, s2) -> eval_seq eval state s1 s2
  | If(e, s1, s2) -> eval_if eval state e s1 s2
  | While(e, s) -> eval_while eval state e s
```

And here is an example of called function in the right-hand part of the pattern matching :

```
let eval_add f state e1 e2 =
  let x1 = f state e1 in
  let x1' =
    match is_int x1 with
    | None -> failwith ""
    | Some x1' -> x1'
  in
  let x2 = f state e2 in
  let x2' =
    match is_int x2 with
    | None -> failwith ""
    | Some x2' -> x2'
  in
  match add x1' x2' with
  | None -> failwith ""
  | Some x0 -> x0
```

Don't mind the undocumented failures, the code is still being built at the moment. For the 'eval' function, I'm getting this error message and I cannot understand it :

```
This definition has type 'a -> ('a, 'b) term -> 'b
which is less general than 'a0 'b0. 'a0 -> ('a0, 'b0) term -> 'b0
```

Did someone have the same error message ? How can I make it disappear ? I guess it comes from the recursive call to 'eval', which I cannot really avoid. Thanks for your help !

Comment: My guess would be that you should drop the `a b.` from your function signature

Comment: The error is probably triggered by a wrong type annotation.  However, the annotation on `eval` is the right one. In fact, the error does not arise in your code example, thus it is hard to guess its source. You should trim down your example and post a full-contained version.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. @Bergi I needed the `a b.` part, because these are GADT types, not generic ones. An `('a, 'b) term` would match any tuple of types, whereas the `(a, b)` one only matches `state` and `value`.
@octachron The error came from the non mutually recursive definition. The `f` parameter I was forced to add to every function did not really know its type, the type inference either chose state or value according to the function's body, but was not able to know it could return both types.
The solution I found is to include all the functions into `eval`'s definition.

Comment: Where exactly is the typing error?

Answer (score 5):

First, let's add some hypotheses to circumvent the missing code:

#### Hypothesis 1:

You are using merlin. In this case, the error message

> This definition has type 'a -> ('a, 'b) term -> 'b
>   which is less general than 'a0 'b0. 'a0 -> ('a0, 'b0) term -> 'b0

sometime happens to mask the real error message

#### Hypothesis 2:

Your `eval_if` and `eval_while` function look like

```
let eval_if eval state e s1 s2 =
  if (to_bool @@ eval state e) then
    eval state s1
  else
    eval state s2
```

and

```
let eval_while eval st e s =
  let st = ref st in
  while (to_bool @@ eval !st e) do
    st := eval !st s
  done; !st
```

#### Answer:

Then the true error lies in the fact that with these definitions both `eval_while` and `eval_if` returns a value and not a state. Indeed, the line `to_bool @@ eval !st e` implies that the function argument `eval` must returns a value. Thus all subsequent call to `eval state x` returns a value since functions arguments are not polymorphic.

This can be fixed either by providing two evals functions, one for values and one for states to `eval_while` and `eval_if` or by wrapping the argument `eval` inside an record with a polymorphic field (which is OCaml way to emulate higher-rank polymorphism see http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/polymorphism.html#sec60):

```
type eval = { eval: 'a 'b. 'a -> ('a,'b) term -> 'b }
let eval_if {eval} state e s1 s2 =
  if (to_bool @@ eval state e) then
    eval state s1
  else
    eval state s2
let eval_while {eval} st e s =
  let st = ref st in
  while (to_bool @@ eval !st e) do
    st := eval !st s
  done; !st
```

then the following slightly amended `eval` function should work:

```
let rec eval : type a b. a -> (a, b) term -> b = fun state term ->
  match term with
  | Const lit -> eval_lit_int state lit
  | Var ident -> eval_var eval state ident
  | Plus(e1, e2) -> eval_add eval state e1 e2
  | Equ(e1, e2) -> eval_eq eval state e1 e2
  | Neg e -> eval_neg eval state e
  | Skip -> eval_skip eval state
  | Asn(ident, e) -> eval_asn eval state ident e
  | Seq(s1, s2) -> eval_seq eval state s1 s2
  | If(e, s1, s2) -> eval_if {eval} state e s1 s2
  | While(e, s) -> eval_while {eval} state e s
```